# Identify variable causing memory error

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, gdb, segmentation-fault

So I have run into a weird error a few times now and im looking for some good directions as to identify the problem.

Basically what I am seeing is a seg-fault. The symptoms are as follows:

1. It occurs only when the program is in release mode, not in debug.
2. It appears as a segfault and GDB tells me that it is in `_list_release`/`_free()`/`free()` at the end of a function.

   `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`

   `0xb0328af8 in _list_release () from /usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/x86/lib/libc.so.3`

   `(gdb) bt`

   `0  0xb0328af8 in _list_release () from /usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/x86/lib/libc.so.3`

   `1  0xb032a464 in __free () from /usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/x86/lib/libc.so.3`

   `2  0xb0329f7d in free () from /usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/x86/lib/libc.so.3`
3. I am not using any dynamic memory (except for what might appear in Eigen (or other libraries)
4. I can print all local variables just before the end of the function, so its not a double free.

Last time this happened it was a memory fault which fits all of these problems. Annoyingly this time i cannot find the problem.

What i would like to do is the following:

1. This would be extra useful: How can I force this error in Debug mode, then GDB would be way more helpful.
2. What is the best way to track down what little bugger is causing the problem. **NOTE:** I cannot use valgrind, it does not work on the operating system i am using (QNX)

Any help would be great.

Comment: `I can print all local variables just before the end of the function, so its not a double free.` A double free is undefined behaviour, so that's not necessarily true.

Comment: @chris Ok, well how would I test that?

Comment: Well, the best way to avoid these is to employ RAII and the like to prevent many of the common causes of segfaults right off the bat. There's always Clang's catch-undefined-behaviour thing, which might help.

Comment: Can your run your application for testing purposes on a more capable platform?

Comment: Continuing on what chris said - consider this: you use a vector, fill it with data and then free its internal storage. The memory is still in possession of process, so attempt to read it will succeed and until someone uses it, you'll even be able to list contents of vector correctly. But attempt to free the vector (for example, leave its scope) will result in AV.

Comment: You guys should add these as answers, I would up vote them, also considering up voting the question so it gets a bit more exposure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It appears as a segfault and GDB tells me that it is in _list_release/_free()/free()

Generally, *any* crash in `free()` is a sign of heap corruption (a double free, a write to free'd memory, freeing unallocated (e.g. stack or global) memory, or an overflow of a heap buffer).

> I am not using any dynamic memory

Yes, you *are*. The fact that you do so indirectly via other libraries is irrelevant.

> I can print all local variables just before the end of the function, so its not a double free.

As many commenters already said, your conclusion doesn't follow: you can access free'd memory just fine, and it may even still contain sensible values.

> How can I force this error in Debug mode, then GDB would be way more helpful.

- You can build with '-O2 -g' (a "release" mode but with debug info enabled).
- GDB will likely *not* be more helpful -- GDB is somewhat useless in debugging heap corruption.

> What is the best way to track down what little bugger

You have a few choices:

- Port your code to a platform where you can use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [AddressSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/)
- Use one of many debugging malloc implementations (dmalloc, mpatrol, etc.). QNX has [one](http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.core_os/wiki/Debug_Malloc).
- Read the code very carefully, making sure that you don't write more data to possibly-malloc'd buffers than you are supposed to.

Comment: So the build with debug flags is interesting. Do you know if this can be set with CMAKE?

Comment: @Ben I am *sure* it can be done with `CMAKE`, but I don't know the details.

Comment: Can I add as well that I have transferred it to Ubuntu but the error doesnt occur on ubuntu. It also doesn't occur when the code is built on a workmates machine (even though it is the same compiler, and cmake version and OS). Any tips for this?