# Eigen Jacobi causing odd segfault in c++

Tags: c++, eigen

So I have the following lines in my code:

```
MatrixXd qdash = zeroCentredMeasurementPointCloud_.topLeftCorner(3, zeroCentredMeasurementPointCloud_.cols());
Matrix3d H = q * qdash.transpose();
Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixXd> svd(H, Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV);
```

Now I am sure that `qdash` and `H` are being initialised correctly (`q` is also, just elsewhere). The last line, involving `Eigen::JacobiSVD` causes the program to throw this error when it is left in:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb0328af8 in _list_release () from /usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/x86/lib/libc.so.3

0  0xb0328af8 in _list_release () from /usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/x86/lib/libc.so.3
1  0xb032a464 in __free () from /usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/x86/lib/libc.so.3
2  0xb0329f7d in free () from /usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/x86/lib/libc.so.3
```

I.E. it is seg-faulting when trying to free it i guess. Now according to the tutorial [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html), all I should have to do to use this functionality is this:

```
MatrixXf m = MatrixXf::Random(3,2);
JacobiSVD<MatrixXf> svd(m, ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV);
```

Can anyone see why it is failing in my case?

Comment: This is the entire stack trace? How can you be sure that "the last line" is causing the SEGFAULT? When I had crashing applications without any clear cause, I ran the code with the tools valgrind or eFence in order to determine weaknesses or problems which might be associated with it.

Comment: What is the Eigen version? Make sure you tested your program with assertions enabled, i.e., without -DNDEBUG or the likes. And as janr said, the stack trace is clearly not complete.

Comment: I think it is the last line because if i comment it out it will run the program to completion. Also this is the same bug that is causing the problems [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190767/identify-variable-causing-memory-error) So i cant use valgrind or debug mode. Also if i include the tutorial code at the bottom of the question into the rogram, then it segfaults on the actual line `JacobiSVD<...` so i am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is super crazy. Turns out I was using Eigen Alignment which doesnt really work on my operating system. This caused an error which would change location just based on the size of the executable that was produced.

The moral of the story is be careful with your includes.